# Is business the only way to become a millionaire?

Tags: investing, business

Is starting my own business venture or investing in someone else's business , the only way to get rich ? I am not looking to become rich quick. I am in no hurry. What are the other options available ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not at all. [The Millionaire Next Door](http://www.thomasjstanley.com/pub-books/1/The_Millionaire_Next_Door.html) offers a book full of anecdotes on couples that earned money and saved their way to being millionaires. I believe about 1/3 or so had businesses, but the rest were employed and simply saved wisely. 
$3860/yr saved for 40 years at 8% will return $1M. Adjust the numbers to hit a million sooner or reach a higher goal.

The Author might be accused of survey bias. This is the phenomenon of studying the final results without looking at the pool of people years prior. Little Adv' is correct that while 1/3 of millionaires may have gotten that way by starting a business, that says nothing about how many businesses need to start to find the one millionaire that resulted. 
I view the book more as a lesson of "spend beneath your means" and focus on his anecdotes of the dual income couples who saved their way to this status. If you are in no rush, get this book from your library and spend the few hours to read it.

In response to my Friend Dilip's comment, [MoneyChimp](http://www.moneychimp.com/features/market_cagr.htm) offers a good look at compound growth (for the S&P) over time. The 40 years ending 2012, which obviously include the 'lost decade,' returned a CAGR of 9.78%. Not to be confused with the average 11.43%. When I pull the numbers for each year's return and apply an annual $3860 deposit, the 40 years ends with $2.2M. A 1% fee, or 1% lower return resulted in $1.6M.

If 8% isn't conservative, of course you can run the numbers you wish. The 40 years contained both a lost decade and two great ones. Will the 3 decades post-lost average to get the Quad-Decade period to 8%+? I don't know.

Comment: Thinking about this, I know CEO of many big companies earn many millions of dollar in a year as their salary.

Comment: In the US, just over 1% of people have accumulated over $2M. The curve is pretty steep beyond that. For income, just under $400K/yr is the 1% level.

Comment: Gee, Joe, please let everyone in on which investment is returning 8% for 40 years! Not as good as the 12% that some gurus are promoting heavily on TV, but not bad nonetheless.  Oh, and +1 by the way :-)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Thanks for the update and the details. Since 40 years have been brought up, perhaps it is worth keeping in mind that it was not possible for _hoi polloi_ such as myself to invest in the S&P 500 Index in 1973, 40 years ago. In those days, one had to be super-rich to be able to afford to invest in 500 companies simultaneously. The Vanguard S&P 500 Index Fund was, I believe, the first S&P 500 Index Fund, and it began operations only in 1976 and finally it was possible for small-time investors to have a part of their portfolio track the S&P 500 Index.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - I am 50, so my real investing life started around 1980 or so. You are right, in a sense there was little actual indexing pre-76. Not sure how I'll use that fact to still discuss data looking backward.

Comment: I am just out of college and I may be way off the mark but isn't 40 years too looong? #justsaying :-)

Comment: @R11G - When I use actual data, starting 40 years ago, it only took 26 years to pass the $1M level. The 40 year number isn't cast in stone. It assumes actually starting to save at 25, and retiring at 65. You should learn to love the spreadsheets, and tinker with the numbers to create your own goals.

Answer (score 3):

That's actually a pretty good way to get bankrupt quick. You can get rich quick through lottery, gambling, mere saving or investing wisely, or marrying someone from the Kennedy or Bush clans. Starting a business is one of the ways to become a millionaire, but definitely not the only one.

Comment: If you have read my question and description below, I clearly stated it does *NOT* need to be quick.

Comment: @ashwin - Agreed, I think he missed that. Yours wasn't a get-rich-quick question.

Comment: @ashwin took out the "quickest" portion, I know that's not what you meant